# Windows store application icon has invalid format and margins

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-apps, assets

I'm using makeappx along with a manifest.appx to generate an application package for the Windows store.

My uap:VisualElements goes like this:

```
<uap:VisualElements DisplayName="tevolution"
                    Description="tevolution is a Remote Video Screen for Motion Freedom."
                    Square44x44Logo="44.png"
                    Square150x150Logo="150.png"
                    BackgroundColor="#323232">
    <uap:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="71.png"
                     Square310x310Logo="310.png"
                     Wide310x150Logo="wide.png"/>
</uap:VisualElements>
```

With the following visual resources:

[image]

Now, for some reason I'm getting a weird icon with additionnal margins on the start menu and the task bar:

[image]
[image]

After publishing to the Windows store, I was expecting margin-less icons and got weird margins with the provided BackgroundColor in both the start menu and the task bar.

I'm not exactly sure where those margins come from and how to fix them. If someone found a way I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `BackgroundColor` to transparent? transparentis one of the [supported background color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-visualelements#remarks).

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this. Also I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion#optional-add-target-based-unplated-assets

Comment: Sure, hope it helps to solve your issue.

Comment: Well it doesn't now the background is blue, like default Windows blue or something

Comment: I'll be investigating this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion#optional-add-target-based-unplated-assets 

and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/iconography/app-icon-construction

Comment: There is a note saying **If you do not include the targetsize-*-altform-unplated assets above your icon will scale to a smaller size and will get an undesirable backplate behind the icon on Taskbar and Start.** It seems to be the explanation of your behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had to copy the following in an assets folder at the root of the project.

```
icon.png (512x512)

icon.scale-100.png (50x50)
icon.scale-125.png (63x63)
icon.scale-150.png (75x75)
icon.scale-200.png (100x100)
icon.scale-400.png (200x200)

Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png (44x44)
Square44x44Logo.scale-125.png (55x55)
Square44x44Logo.scale-150.png (66x66)
Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png (88x88)
Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png (176x176)

Square44x44Logo.targetsize-16.png  (16x16)
Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24.png  (24x24)
Square44x44Logo.targetsize-32.png  (32x32)
Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png  (48x48)
Square44x44Logo.targetsize-256.png (256x256)

Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-16.png  (16x16)
Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-24.png  (24x24)
Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-32.png  (32x32)
Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-48.png  (48x48)
Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-256.png (256x256)

Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-16.png  (16x16)
Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-24.png  (24x24)
Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-32.png  (32x32)
Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-48.png  (48x48)
Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-256.png (256x256)

Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png (150x150)
Square150x150Logo.scale-125.png (188x188)
Square150x150Logo.scale-150.png (225x255)
Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png (300x300)
Square150x150Logo.scale-400.png (600x600)

SmallTile.scale-100.png (71x71)
SmallTile.scale-125.png (89x89)
SmallTile.scale-150.png (107x107)
SmallTile.scale-200.png (142x142)
SmallTile.scale-400.png (284x284)

LargeTile.scale-100.png (310x310)
LargeTile.scale-125.png (388x388)
LargeTile.scale-150.png (465x465)
LargeTile.scale-200.png (620x620)
LargeTile.scale-400.png (1240x1240)

WideTile.scale-100.png (310x150)
WideTile.scale-125.png (388x188)
WideTile.scale-150.png (465x225)
WideTile.scale-200.png (620x300)
WideTile.scale-400.png (1240x600)
```

Then, added the following to AppxManifest.xml:

```
<uap:VisualElements DisplayName="tevolution"
                    Description="tevolution is a Remote Video Screen for Motion Freedom."
                    Square44x44Logo="assets/Square44x44Logo.png"
                    Square150x150Logo="assets/Square150x150Logo.png"
                    BackgroundColor="transparent">
    <uap:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="assets/SmallTile.png"
                     Square310x310Logo="assets/LargeTile.png"
                     Wide310x150Logo="assets/WideTile.png"/>
</uap:VisualElements>
```

Then, I ran the following at the root folder of my project:

```
makepri createconfig /cf priconfig.xml /dq "en-US"

makepri new /pr . /cf priconfig.xml
```

I have no idea why anyone wouldn't figure that out.